# docker pull failing with = FATA[0001]: x509: not index.docker.io

Tags: docker

I have docker running on a VM on the corporate LAN and it all works fine.

I have a second deploying in an other part of the business that required me to add a lot of http_proxy settings to the /etc/environments file. I had to do this to enable apt-get to work so I could install docker.

However, a docker pull fails with the message below.

Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

I am running ubuntu 14.04

> FATA[0001] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: x509: certificate is valid for FG3K6C3A15800008, not index.docker.io